# How can I kill pre-up shell in order to login?

Tags: networking

I add "pre-up bash /something/ipadd.sh" to interfaces, but this .sh file never stop.
I push Ctrl+C, ESC, but no success.

How can I skip/kill/pause this pre-up script, and login to the consle normally?

(removed from a network. No LAN cable/Wireless attached.)

Answer (score 1):

I would login with ssh across your network if it is available and kill it from there.
(Sorry just seen no ethernet attached) - so this answer is no applicable! :(